# PHP Client to verify https certificates

Tags: php, web-services, ssl, https

I need to create a php that will act as a client and use some web services under https.
My Problem is that I also want to verify the server certificate.I need to know that I have the right server and that there is no one the middle that acts as the server.
Can someone help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Good step to take, but not useful to check for man-in-the-middle attacks. Google "Diginotar" to see why the entire SSL CA system is fundamentally broken.

Comment: @Marc B: Without disagreeing in any fundamental sense, I'd like to note that you can avoid many of the issues in practice if you take care to keep the list of trusted CAs as short as possible. For example, in a case like this, there's really no need to trust any CA other than the specific one used by the site you're connecting to.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the curl extension, it can be configured to verify a certificate on connection.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

```
// As of writing this, Twitter uses Verisign, Google uses Eqifax
$exampleUrl = 'https://twitter.com/'; // Success
$exampleUrl = 'https://google.com/';  // Fails

// create a new CURL resource
$ch = curl_init($exampleUrl);

// enable verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

// list of CAs to trust
// If the remote site has a specific CA, they usually have a .crt
// file on their site you can download.  Or you can export key items from
// some browsers.
// In this example, using: Verisign [1]
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . '/ca_bundle.crt');
// - or -
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, __DIR__ . '/ca_certs/');

// If the remote site uses basic auth:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);

// And a helpful option to enable while debugging
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

// defaults to stdout, don't want that for this case.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$page = curl_exec($ch);
```

[1] http://www.verisign.com/support/verisign-intermediate-ca/extended-validation/apache/

Comment: Thanks! sorry for the dumb question. but I don't see how can I test a Url or use as a web service client. I am really new in to php. :)

Comment: The connection will fail if the server does not provide a valid certificate signed by one of the CAs in the ca_bundle.crt

Comment: Thanks for the help! But, still both the first and the second calls does not issue any warning. and when I do 'var_dump($page)' i get Boolean false. Please help... :) 
And after that how can I call the server functions? (e.g, like soap client?)

Comment: Please note a bug in the above code: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` should be an integer parameter, and should be set to 2 (the default). See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php for more details. If you set the value to `true`, you're actually disabling host checking, and therefore enabling MITM attacks!

Comment: @LeighSimpson Thank you.  Edited the answer to correct for it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like as of Curl 7.10, this is all set to be checked by default now:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

---

> CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER
>
> FALSE to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate. Alternate certificates to verify against can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAINFO option or a certificate directory can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAPATH option.
>
> TRUE by default as of cURL 7.10. Default bundle installed as of cURL 7.10.

---

> CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST
>
> 1 to check the existence of a common name in the SSL peer certificate. 2 to check the existence of a common name and also verify that it matches the hostname provided. In production environments the value of this option should be kept at 2 (default value).