# Setup Google Compute Engine to only be accessible from a Google App Engine application?

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, google-compute-engine

Google Compute Engine instances can be secured behind a firewall that allows you to open the instance by ports and/or IP addresses.

Google App Engine doesn't use a single IP address.

I have a Compute Engine server running Nginx that I would like to completely lock down so the only way to access it is through an application on Google App Engine, is this possible?

If not, is there a simple way to send a POST request with a string of characters to Nginx, that if not present, the Nginx server would send people to a 404?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845305/only-allow-app-engine-to-speak-or-connect-to-compute-engine?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTP authentication as per the question Dan has linked to. There is no viable network/IP/firewall mechanism to restrict access.

The HTTP authentication works just fine!